# How does node import happen when importing from features module?

Tags: 7, features

I used the Node export module to export few pages into features; when I import it is randomly imported.

Is there any particular pattern that it is followed while importing? I want to make a particular page as node 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of thing is not really possible. The problem is that the node id is serial, so on one machine it will have on id but on another machine it will have another id. Also the the node id is the primary identification, so changing it is not always that easy (if you have comments etc.)

For this kind of thing, UUIDs is really needed (Universally Unique ID). There are modules for this in Drupal 7 and it's being worked on in Drupal 8, but neither will effect the node id, instead it will maintain a UUID which will be the same on all machines that has the node imported.

Comment: There are only 3 nodes that i export and import.

Comment: @Hacker The problem is not with how many nodes you export and import, but with the number of nodes already present in the Drupal site where the nodes are imported. What googletorp says is still valid, even when the site has two nodes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  - Its just a fresh site and i am importing this node by means of feature using installation profiles..

Comment: @Hacker Most likely you can look at the source and change the order of an array, to change when nodes are imported, but this will most likely be reverted by Features at some point. Tying logic to a serial id is generally a bad idea, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @googletorp - Just a quick demo to client about power of installation profiles and features. So that as soon as its installed, atleast home page comes up with few sliders and blocks and boxes and with few basic configuration  pre done.

Comment: @Hacker Why would you need specific nids for a demo?

Comment: @googletorp - Its not about specific nids. I do a site configuration so that node 1 is my home page or front page. And export it in features and import and show to client. So now when the site comes up, its node1 shld come up as home rite?

Comment: @hacker Why not load the node by title instead? On a fresh site, that should always work even tough titles are not unique.

Comment: @googletorp - I am not aware of what you are suggesting. If you can be more elaborate, i can give it a try.

Comment: @Hacker Instead of hardcoding which node to set as the front page, you can get the node with the specific title (the one to set as front page) and then use that for the front page url - node/[nid]